# TTS is not looping properly from IU Thread in android?

Tags: java, android, android-service, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

Always speak last elements. But i want speak first Bangladesh then India then Barma also finally speak Tanana. When i run my codes then always speak Tanana.

My Codes:

```
int wordNumber=0;
String[] splitspeech = { "Bangladesh", "India", "Barma",
                        "Banana", "Tanana" };
                do {
                    reader(splitspeech[wordNumber]);
                    wordNumber++;
                } while (wordNumber < splitspeech.length);


public void reader(final String msg) {
        Log.e("reader output:", "msg:" + msg);
        TextToSpeech textReader = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(),
                new OnInitListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onInit(int status) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,
                                "Hello");

                        textReader.speak(msg,

                        TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, map);

                    }
                });
    }
```

How to implement that is speak according to loop. that means fisrt speak first elements that means Bangladesh and at last speak Tanana (last element). Please help me. I don't know it is easy or not. but it is very complex for me. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QUEUE_ADD` instead of `QUEUE_FLUSH`. You are clearing the TTS queue in this way.